# How is it possible to smoothing the edges of an image using CSS?

Tags: css, image

When I tried to add an image in to my website its edges feel very rough.

[image](**note:** in the above image you can see the rough surface around the berry).

This happened when I removed its background using an image editor.Is it possible to smooth the edges using css? If yes,then how?

thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: by using border-radius it can be done some what..

Comment: Use a better image editor or a better algorithm to remove the background and smoothen the edges. It's not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't try to fix this using css.** Instead use a png24 (not png8 or gif) because that has proper alpha (transparency) and remove the background colour by using the background colour as an alpha mask (or similar technique).

You can do all this with free software like GIMP if you don't have something like PhotoShop

**Edit:** I just noticed that [it's available as an svg](http://thinkberries.com/assets/img/thinkberries-logo.svg), why aren't you using that?